# Trying to test a component using the useQuery hook but onCompleted causing issues

Tags: graphql, jestjs, react-apollo, react-testing-library

I am trying to test the following component, but cannot get it to render in Jest once data is fetched due to an error on the query's onCompleted prop. I have another component that is essentially the same, but does not utilise onCompleted at all and presents no trouble to Jest.

Here is the component in question, with some code reduced for brevity purposes:

```
import { trackProductListView } from "src/shared/components/analytics";
import searchResourcesQuery from "./search-resources.graphql";
const SearchResources = ({ filter, orderBy, query }) => {
  const { loading, error, data, fetchMore } = useQuery(searchResourcesQuery, {
    variables: {
      orderBy,
      filter,
      query
    },
    onCompleted: ({ searchResources: { results } }) =>
      results && trackProductListView("Search", null, results, 1)
  });
...

  return (
    <div>
      {!results.length ? (
        <EmptySearch variant="resources" />
      ) : (
        <InfiniteResources
          trackContext="Search"
          hasMore={!!searchAfter}
          loadMoreEntries={loadMoreEntries}
          resources={results}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And here is the test, although I have removed the mock results (again, for brevity purposes):

```
import React from "react";
import { act, wait } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import { MockedProvider } from "@apollo/react-testing";
import renderWithRouter from "src/shared/test-utils/renderWithRouter.js";
import SearchResources from "./search-resources";
import searchResourcesQuery from "./search-resources.graphql";
const mocks = [
  {
    request: {
      query: searchResourcesQuery,
      variables: { query: "test" }
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        searchResources: {
          searchAfter: null,
          results: [],
          __typename: "ResourceList"
        }
      }
    }
  }
];
it("renders", async () => {
  const { getByText } = renderWithRouter(
    <MockedProvider addTypename={false} mocks={mocks}>
      <SearchResources query="test" />
    </MockedProvider>
  );
  await act(() => wait(() => getByText("Resource Partner Link test")));
  expect(getByText("Resource Partner Link test")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Running these tests results in:

```
TypeError: (0 , _analytics.trackProductListView) is not a function
```

Any help fixing this is most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out I could just mock the trackProductListView function